# PowerShell Script Cannot Write to File Share via Group Policy Startup Script

Tags: powershell, group-policy

I have added a PowerShell script as a Group Policy computer startup script. The script runs fine and does all of the tasks fine. However, at the end of the script, it is supposed to copy a log file to a file share, which it is not doing. The file share shows that "SYSTEM" has full control, so I'm not sure what the issue is. I'm able to run the script as admin while on the same machine and it will copy the log to the server without a problem. It does not do this via computer startup script (under SYSTEM account) though. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to give the computer account write permissions on the network share. When the SYSTEM account is used to access a network resource it will do so as the domain account of the computer (DOMAIN\COMPUTER$).

Comment: I plan on running this script on over 1,000 machines. How would I go about assuring that all of these have access to write to the file share?

Comment: Add the computers to a new security group and give that group write access to the share, or if you plan on running this script on all computers in the domain, grant access to Domain Computers.

Comment: Thanks - The GPO does have a GPO apply group so I just gave that group write permissions to the file share. Appears to be working now.